# Android BLE connect with MAC address

Tags: android, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have tried to connect Arduino and Android phone with BLE.

But it doesn't work.

I want app to connect with a specific device that has a specific name and MAC address.

I declare Mac address

```
private static String Adr = "D4:36:39:6F:7F:0E";
```

and etc

```
private BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic;
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
private int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
private Handler mHandler;
private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 10000;
private BluetoothLeScanner mLEScanner;
private ScanSettings settings;
private List<ScanFilter> filters;
private BluetoothGatt mGatt;
private SharedPreferences setting;
```

and made some classes.

parts of clasees are

```
private ScanCallback mScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
        Log.i("callbackType", String.valueOf(callbackType));
        Log.i("result", result.toString());
        btDevice = result.getDevice();

        if (btDevice != null && btDevice.getName() != null && btDevice.getName().contains("Device"))
            connectToDevice(btDevice);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
        for (ScanResult sr : results) {
            Log.i("ScanResult - Results", sr.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
        Log.e("Scan Failed", "Error Code: " + errorCode);
    }
};

private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
    new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi,
                             byte[] scanRecord) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.i("onLeScan", device.toString());
                    connectToDevice(device);
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

and I searched internet and modified

```
public void connectToDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
    if (mGatt == null) {
        btDevice = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(CantusAdr); 
        mGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, gattCallback);
    }
}
```

to connect with a arduino device.

and

```
private ScanCallback mScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
        Log.i("callbackType", String.valueOf(callbackType));
        Log.i("result", result.toString());
        btDevice = result.getDevice();

        if (btDevice != null && btDevice.getName() != null && btDevice.getName().contains("Device"))
            connectToDevice(btDevice);
    }
```

This codes for connecting with named "Device" which has mac address 
"D4:36:39:6F:7F:0E"

App is working.

It connect with one device, but not with "Device""D4~~~".

How can i solve it?

Please help me.

Answer (score 4):

If you already know the address of the device you want to connect to, you don't need to do the Bluetooth LE scanning. This should be enough:

```
BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice("D4:36:39:6F:7F:0E");
device.connectGatt(this, false, gattCallback);
```

Comment: Can you tell me more precisely? Where should i put this code in my codes? and Which codes are uesless?

Comment: how can i ensure that device is on if i don't make a scan ?